# set_workspace moveit not working

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi friends,

I am working with MoveIt and Panda from Franka Emika. I am trying to set the workspace for the robot in Moveit to limit Joints Movement to avoid crashs. But it not seems to have any effekt to the robot.

Function is available for move_group in PythonAPI:
https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/master/moveit_commander/src/moveit_commander/move_group.py

My script looks like the following:

```
group = moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander("panda_arm")

## [minX, minY, minZ, maxX, maxY, maxZ]
ws = [0.2, -0.3, 0.3, 0.7, 0.3, 0.7]
group.set_workspace(ws)
```

The script will fail due to an error if ws isn't well formed (e.g. ws with 7 entries) which tells me that I am doing the function-call correct ..

If there are other ways to limit joint movements (in Space), I appreciate any idea or hints.

Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392526/set_workspace-moveit-not-working/) by [Qualityland](https://answers.ros.org/users/41876/qualityland/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Qualityland,

Have a look at this answer, #q273485 in short you cannot add revolutionary joints.

Instead, you can add a collision object to the region you want to avoid. you can have a look at [moveit collision object adding](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/planning_scene_ros_api/planning_scene_ros_api_tutorial.html#add-an-object-into-the-environment) or you can follow this answer #q209030.

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2021-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1